# emacs change the file in a specific window

Tags: emacs, window

I'd like to implement a function to show a file I want in a specific window and I also would like to change the file to an another one in that window in case I want to. But I couldn't find any appropriate API.
Could you give me some advices to write this sort of functions, please?
I can get an window id from (split-window-xxx) but I can't imagine what elisp API can have it displayed the file I want to.
Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
(with-selected-window window
  (find-file f))
```

or if you want to load a buffer

```
(with-selected-window window
  (switch-to-buffer buf))
```

Answer (score 1):

The lower-level control you might be looking for are `find-file-noselect` which opens a file and returns the buffer without displaying it, and `set-window-buffer` which lets you change the buffer displayed by a particular window.